# Incrementer inside loop adds more than one, why?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to increment the values inside of an array that corresponds to how many times that discount has been used. The incrementation works well if the discount is 0% (`discount = 1.0`) but for 20%, 30%, and 40% (`discount is 0.8, 0.7, 0.6` respectively) the related index in the `counts` array is incremented by 2. Finally, if `discount = 0.5` `counts[4]` is incremented by 8. I feel like it has something to do with what iteration of the for loop I'm in but I can't figure it out.

Heres the class that I think holds the problem:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package softwaresales;
/**
 *
 * @author python
 */
public class SoftwareSales {
    private int unitsSold;
    private final double UNIT_PRICE = 99.0;
    private final int[] UNITS_LOW_RANGES = {1, 10, 20, 50, 100};
    private final double[] DISCOUNTS = {1.0, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5};
    private static int[] counts = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    SoftwareSales(int u){
        unitsSold = u;
    }

    public int getUnitsSold(){
        return unitsSold;
    }

    public double getDiscount(){
        double discount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if((unitsSold >= UNITS_LOW_RANGES[i]) &&
                    (unitsSold < UNITS_LOW_RANGES[i+1])){
                counts[i] += 1;
                discount = DISCOUNTS[i];
            }
            else if (unitsSold >= 100){
                counts[4] += 1;
                discount = DISCOUNTS[4];
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        return discount;
    }

    public double getCost(){
        return unitsSold * UNIT_PRICE * getDiscount();
    }

    public int[] getCounts(){
        return counts;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample input :

```
13
31
115
101
96
8
29
103
27
129
```

And the related output:

```
Units sold: 13
Discount: 19.999999999999996%
Price: $1029.6000000000001

Units sold: 31
Discount: 30.000000000000004%
Price: $2148.2999999999997

Units sold: 115
Discount: 50.0%
Price: $5692.5

Units sold: 101
Discount: 50.0%
Price: $4999.5

Units sold: 96
Discount: 40.0%
Price: $5702.4

Units sold: 8
Discount: 0.0%
Price: $792.0

Units sold: 29
Discount: 30.000000000000004%
Price: $2009.6999999999998

Units sold: 103
Discount: 50.0%
Price: $5098.5

Units sold: 27
Discount: 30.000000000000004%
Price: $1871.1

Units sold: 129
Discount: 50.0%
Price: $6385.5

=================
=               =
=   DISCOUNTS   =
=               =
=================
0% discounts: 1
20% discounts: 2
30% discounts: 6
40% discounts: 2
50% discounts: 32
```

As you can see there is only one instance where a 0% discount was given which is represented in the output. There is also only one instance each of 20% and 40% discounts but the output shows 2 for each, similar to the 30% discount. Also there was 4 instances of a 50% discount being given, but as you can see the array was incremented 32 times...

Here's my main program where I call `getDiscount()`.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package softwaresales;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author python
 */
public class SofwareSalesDriver {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file_location;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        CreateInputFile inputs = new CreateInputFile();
        System.out.println("Enter the PATH to the folder where you would like" +
                " the in/out files: ");
        System.out.println("\nExamples:\nLinux: /home/%USER_NAME%/Documents/" + 
                "\nor Windows: C:\\\\users\\\\%USER_NAME%\\\\Documents\\\\");
        System.out.print("\nEnter PATH: ");
        file_location = kb.nextLine();
        String infile = file_location + "Inputs.txt";
        String outfile = file_location + "Outfile.txt";
        File file = new File(outfile);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        int unitsSold = 0;
        SoftwareSales customer = new SoftwareSales(unitsSold);
        int[] counts = customer.getCounts();
        inputs.createInputFile(file_location);
        Scanner fileLine = new Scanner(new File(infile));
        while (fileLine.hasNextInt()){
            unitsSold = fileLine.nextInt();
            customer = new SoftwareSales(unitsSold);
            writer.write("Units sold: " + unitsSold + "\n" + 
                    "Discount: " + (1 - customer.getDiscount())*100 + "%\n" +
                    "Price: $" + customer.getCost() + "\n\n");
        }
        writer.write("=================\n=               =\n" +
                "=   DISCOUNTS   =\n=               =\n" +
                "=================\n" + 
                "0% discounts: "+ counts[0] / 2 +
                "\n20% discounts: " + counts[1] + 
                "\n30% discounts: " + counts[2] + 
                "\n40% discounts: " + counts[3] + 
                "\n50% discounts: " + counts[4] + "\n\n");

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"As you can see there is only one instance where a 0% discount was given which is represented in the output."* - That looks like expected behaviour to me, because you've only got one number below 10 in your inputs.

Comment: Yes, sorry I tried to make it apparent that when the discount is 0% the program performs as intended, but only when the discount is at 0%. You are correct in the fact that the behavior you pointed out is expected.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your code correctly, the error is related to the `if`-statement in your `for` loop. You should have the check before the `for` loop, otherwise you increment the counter multiple times per loop if `unitsSold >= 100` because the `else` statement is called for each loop iteration.

```
if (unitsSold >= 100){
    counts[4] += 1;
    discount = DISCOUNTS[4];
    System.out.print("*");
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if((unitsSold >= UNITS_LOW_RANGES[i]) &&
                (unitsSold < UNITS_LOW_RANGES[i+1])){
            counts[i] += 1;
            discount = DISCOUNTS[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for the double counting of some numbers is due to that function:

```
public double getCost(){
    return unitsSold * UNIT_PRICE * getDiscount();
}
```

Here, you call `getDiscount()` again, which will again trigger the whole process and add the respective value to `counts[i]`.

I would recommend you the following: Instead of calculating the discount twice, you could just pass the discount as a parameter like `getCost(double discount)`.
This way, you prevent calling this function twice.

Just a quick notice at the end: Normally, you should refrain from performing modifications of global variables in getters if you do not intend to actually count the number of getter-calls. Probably, the discount calculation could be moved to the constructor and the getDiscount() only returns the discount that has been previously calculated in the constructor. But that just as a side note.

Comment: That fixed one issue, but still if `discount is 0.2, 0.3, or 0.4` then `counts[i] += 1` still adds 2 each time.. Do I need to pull that conditional out of the for loop too? Or is there a way around that? For reference there is examples in the last 5 lines of my sample output

Comment: Could you provide me with the code where you call the getDiscount() function? The rest of the code seems to work fine for me locally.

Comment: Okay, I posted it. Is there some equivalent to python's `break` in java? I feel like that would solve my problem, after `getDiscount()` increments `counts[i]` by 1 if it hit a `break` statement and terminated the loop, that should work. Would that be considered janky?

Comment: Thank you. I found the error and will add it to the answer now.

Comment: What is the purpose in counting how many times a getter is called?

Comment: Ahhh finally, i just spent 30 minutes trying to figure out why `counts[0]` was returning the wrong value... I had divided the result by 2 in my driver program for testing lol... Everything seems to be working now. I moved the `getCost()` and `getDiscount()` logic to the constructor, I don't immediately see why this is better, but if it's good practice I'll continue doing it. Thanks for the help. Loops are a lot pickier in JAVA lol.